# How can I remove duplicates from my foreach loop

Tags: php

I've got this foreach loop, that I use inside a select to get the options from my database. but I get a lot of duplicates. This is my code.

```
 <select  id="selectid" name="selectOrdre_nummer" class="select custom-select col-md-1" onchange="callthis();">
  <option default disabled>-- select an option --</option>
  <option value=""> None </option>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <?php foreach ($csv->getGodOrdre_nummerTable() as $select) { ?>
      <option class="option" value="<?= $select->Ordre_nummer ?>"><?= $select->Ordre_nummer ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------>
</select>
```

This is an attempt I've tried without any luck:

```
<script>$("select .option").val(function(idx, val) {
  $(this).siblings('[value="'+ val +'"]').remove();
});
</script>
```

Have also tried doing this :

```
<?php foreach ($csv->getGodVarenummerTable() as $select) {
          $varenummer = json_decode(json_encode($select->Varenummer), True);
          array_unique($varenummer);
?>
          <option class="option" value="<?= $varenummer?>"><?= $varenummer ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `array_unique`?

Comment: Use group by in query, show us your query

Comment: If you get the options from your database why don't you use `DISTINCT` in your query ?

Comment: Thanks alot will do!

Comment: Your attempt at using array_unique focused on the wrong data element to begin with - it is not $select containing the duplicates, but the result of $csv->getGodVarenummerTable()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built function array_unique to create a new array of unique values only, essentially removing your duplicates.

```
<select  id="selectid" name="selectOrdre_nummer" class="select custom-select col-md-1" onchange="callthis();">
  <option default disabled>-- select an option --</option>
  <option value=""> None </option>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
    $unique_array = array_unique($csv->getGodOrdre_nummerTable());
    <?php foreach ($unique_array as $select) { ?>
      <option class="option" value="<?= $select->Ordre_nummer ?>"><?= $select->Ordre_nummer ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------>
</select>
```

While this work, you may want to look into optimising your query instead, to select only unique values at the point of query, therefore returning less data.

Answer (score 1):

Didnt know about DISTINCT Worked like a dream. here is the answer!

```
public function getGodOrdre_nummerTable()
    {
        return $this->db->toList("SELECT DISTINCT  Ordre_nummer FROM `Angle`");
    }
```